# Can't require css file with react/webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I am trying to import my css file and I keep getting this error. `Cannot find module './style.css'`. I modified my `webpack.config.js` with no luck. Please any guidance or help is appreciated. Yes, Home.js and style.css are in the same directory.

`webpack.config.js`

```
...module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-1']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')
      }
    ]
}...
```

`style.css`

```
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

`Home.js`

```
import './style.css'
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [doc](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin#extracting-sass-or-less) this should work;

```
...module: {
    rules: [
      ...
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader']
        })
      }
    ]
}...
```